# SEO indexing with dynamic titles, keywords and descriptions

Tags: seo, ip-address, meta-tags, title, local-seo

I'm working on a website (all in one single domain) so I'm wondering to create dynamic titles, descriptions, keywords and headings for each location.

What I'm doing is to get information from the IP address of the user and show for example a dynamic title:

```
var userCity = codeToGetCityFromIP;

<title>Welcome to userCity</title>
// and same for description, keywords and headings...
```

Obviously the code is different.

I'd like to know if it is a good solution to create multiple SEO indexing based on cities?

I'm also using *GeoLocation* and I do same using the returned values from it.

I'm doing right or there are more effective ways to indexing in different countries and cities without create multiple website for each city of the world?

Comment: You're making an unreliable assumption that the city reported will always be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see is that a search engine bot will "see", and therefore crawl and index, a page with a title optimised to the location of the bot. If it's in Chicago, it indexes a page with the title `<title>Welcome to Chicago</title>`, and that's what's shown to any user, regardless of where they are or what terms they search.

Also, what about the actual content? You're changing the title, keywords and meta description to match the location of the IP, but you can't re-write *content* to be relevant to each IP's location.

Might be a breach of guidelines for some engines, too. [Google's Webmaster Guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769), for example, prohibit "automatically generated content", which is essentially what you're proposing.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is I would first create a generic title that would be acceptable for anyone who viewed your site from any location (a really lame title is "welcome"). Then I would make the title that anyone without JavaScript falls back to. That title would be what google sees, because google normally doesn't crawl JavaScript.

Then, you could use JavaScript to change the text of the title to match the location of the user. That way, Google wont get confused if they crawl your website using bots from different ip addresses or locations, because they would only see the non-location based title.

Comment: Problem then is that you're showing different content to users than to search engines. That's a breach of Google guidelines, also the site will be ranked and returned for searches based on this "generic" content, which doesn't seem useful.